# Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes after maven shade packaging

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-pubsub

following [this example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-with-error-handler) and [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) I created a program that works in Eclipse development environment, however if I try to package it via maven (mvn clean package) and run it standalone I get this error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException:
> Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

I tried several ways (including using other maven plugin, like `maven-assembly-plugin` with `jar-with-dependencies` descriptorRef), without success getting different error.

this is my main (and only) class:

```
package it.factory.pub;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutures;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiException;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;

public class PublishWithErrorHandler {
    //
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(PublishWithErrorHandler.class);

    //
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String projectId = args[0];
        String topicId = args[1];
        String[] messages = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 2, args.length);
        log.info("projectId: " + projectId);
        log.info("projectId: " + topicId);
        log.info("messages: " + Arrays.toString(messages));
        publishWithErrorHandlerExample(projectId, topicId, messages);
    }

    private static void publishWithErrorHandlerExample(String projectId, String topicId, String[] messages) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
        Publisher publisher = null;
        try {
            // Create a publisher instance with default settings bound to the topic
            publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
            // List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("first message", "second message");
            for (final String message : messages) {
                log.info("Publishing message: '" + message + "'");
                ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
                PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();
                // Once published, returns a server-assigned message id (unique within the topic)
                ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
                // Add an asynchronous callback to handle success / failure
                ApiFutures.addCallback(future, new ApiFutureCallback<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                        if (throwable instanceof ApiException) {
                            ApiException apiException = ((ApiException) throwable);
                            // details on the API exception
                            log.info(apiException.getStatusCode().getCode());
                            log.info(apiException.isRetryable());
                        }
                        log.error("Error publishing message : " + message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
                        // Once published, returns server-assigned message ids (unique within the topic)
                        log.info("Published message ID: " + messageId);
                    }
                }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
            }
        } finally {
            if (publisher != null) {
                // When finished with the publisher, shutdown to free up resources.
                publisher.shutdown();
                publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.factory</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <customer>a2a</customer>
        <log4j2.version>2.12.1</log4j2.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheLicenseResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheNoticeResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>it.factory.pub.PublishWithErrorHandler</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- pub-sub google -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>19.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you already figured this out, but there is a typo in pom.xml, it should be mainClass instead of Main-Class.

Aside from that, what resolved the issue for me was to exclude additional types:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>it.factory.pub.PublishWithErrorHandler</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Since there were some additional SF and RSA files which were triggering the error

Comment: interestingly there's both `mainClass` and `Main-Class` in maven doc [one page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)!